# Is there a way to declare generic type in class and use it with generic parameter in method?

Tags: java, generics

So in Java we have generic Callable interface:

```
public interface Callable<V> {
    V call() throws Exception;
}
```

And I want interface, which use only specific type of Callable, but at the same time, I need V type of Callable in generic method, so in theory it can look like this:

```
public interface CallablePoolExecutor<CALLABLE<?> extends Callable> {
    <V, C extends CALLABLE<V>> void enqueue(
        C callable,
        CallableExecutionListener<V, C> callableExecutionListener
    );
}
```

Is there any syntax to achieve this in Java?

Comment: What would be wrong with just using `C extends Callable<V>`?

Comment: I want to make it possible for executor implementation to accept only fixed subtypes of Callable

Comment: I think this is not possible. You can't specify a generic type with a generic type

Comment: You can't do this whilst retaining the flexibility in `V`. You would have to specify `V` at the class leve.

Comment: Well, thats sad. Thank you.